# Collision detection in transition

Tags: javascript, transition

I have two objects

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var ahead= document.getElementById("follower");
document.addEventListener("click", move_player);

function move_player(e) {
        x_click = e.clientX;
        y_click = e.clientY;
        player.style.transition = "all 0.5s"
        if (x_click < canvas.clientWidth && y_click < canvas.clientHeight){
        player.style.left = x_click - player.clientWidth/2 + "px";
        player.style.top = y_click - player.clientHeight/2 + "px";
        }

var for_ahead = setInterval(function(){ move_ahead() }, 20);
        function move_ahead() {
        ahead.style.left = x_click - ahead.clientWidth+ "px";
        ahead.style.top = y_click - ahead.clientHeight +"px";
        ahead.style.transition = "all 1.4s"
}
```

Imagine i have an object and when I click somewhere it goes there. There is a second object that follows the click but at a lower speed.
Those object will collide if the first object doesn't move soon.

I'm trying to create a collision detection between those two objects using:

```
if(((parseInt(player.style.left) < parseInt(ahead.style.left) + parseInt(ahead.clientWidth))) &&
parseInt(player.style.left) + parseInt(player.clientWidth) > parseInt(ahead.style.left) &&
parseInt(player.style.top) < parseInt(ahead.style.top) + parseInt(ahead.clientHeight) &&
parseInt(player.style.top) + parseInt(player.clientHeight) > parseInt(ahead.style.top))
```

I've added the function above in the for_ahead.

```
var for_ahead = setInterval(function(){ move_ahead() }, 20);
        function move_ahead() {
            if(((parseInt(player.style.left) < parseInt(ahead.style.left) + parseInt(ahead.clientWidth))) && parseInt(player.style.left) + parseInt(player.clientWidth) > parseInt(ahead.style.left) &&
            parseInt(player.style.top) < parseInt(ahead.style.top) + parseInt(ahead.clientHeight) && parseInt(player.style.top) + parseInt(player.clientHeight) > parseInt(ahead.style.top))  alert("Detected collision");
            ahead.style.left = x_click - ahead.clientWidth*2.6+ "px";
            ahead.style.top = y_click - ahead.clientHeight/2 +"px";
            ahead.style.transition = "all 1.4s"
}
```

My problem is that after it calculates the ahead.style.left and ahead.style.top it pops up alert("Detected collision")
It doesn't calculate the collision detection at each moment of the transition. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style.left` returns target value of `left` property, you need to use `getComputedStyle` to get current style value.

I prepared simple fiddle to show how to get current style values using jQuery and VanillaJS.

http://jsfiddle.net/zg69gdh9/2/